resources on how cast between floating point numbers via mantissa/exponent manipulation
I'm trying to understand how conversion between floats works as I'm coding in C++ an example program that attempt to do so, specifically conversion from a wider to a narrower float, accounting for rounding. I'm looking around everywhere on the internet, on the IEEE 754 standard, but I can't find a proper resource that explains how to manipulate the exponent and mantissa parts in order to get from a float to another float, accounting for the rounding error.
Can anyone point me to something useful?
any help is appreciated.

I'll try to find some links, but there's plenty of information, both here on SO and the rest of the internet, on manipulating the individual parts of floating-point values.  Step 1 is to get the bits of a 32-bit or 64-bit float or double into an unsigned integer value (of the same size) so that you can manipulate the bits.  Unions, char * pointers, and memcpy are all popular strategies for accomplishing step 1.  Step 2 is to extract the 23 (or 52) bit significand/mantissa and the 8/11 bit exponent; ordinary C-style shifts and masks are fine for this.

To convert between formats, just grow or shrink the significand, and adjust the exponent.  If the significand needs to grow, pad it on the right with 0's.  If it needs to shrink, lop off bits (again on the right), possibly rounding by looking at the value of the first lopped-off bit.  Adjusting the exponent is straightforward, but you must remember to take both biases into account, and check for overflow.  If there's overflow, you might want to construct an Inf value on output.

Finally, for a complete solution, you'd have to deal with subnormal values (both on input and output), and the special Inf and NaN values.

See plenty of information at this question.  See also this one.

A cast is an operator in C++ that converts. If you use a cast, the C++ implementation converts for you. So your title and question do not make much sense—to cast, you simply write a cast expression. Do you mean to ask how you would do the conversion yourself? If so, you should explain what exactly you are working with and how you intend to work with it. E.g., do you have a double in IEEE-754 binary64 format? Are you going to examine the bytes that represent it or dissect it with standard library routines like frexp? Or do you have some other representation, like a struct with parts?

@EricPostpischil what if I defined a set of implementation defined FP? let's say I have a fp35 or fp40 data type that I want to cast to a some other type - still implementation defined. I can't just "cast" and C++ will take care of it. I have to manipulate the bit fields for exp, mantissa and take care of rounding to make it work, so my question makes sense.

Stop saying “cast.” Once, again, a cast is an operator in C++. It is not a conversion, the same way + and * are not addition or multiplication. They are pieces of text in source code that instruct the compiler to perform an addition or a multiplication. Use the correct name so that you communicate properly with other people. What you want to do is convert from one floating-point format to another…

… Conceptually, this is simple. The problems lie in the details. First, if you have a representation of a floating-point number, such as the bytes that represent it, you need to decode it. For example, IEEE-754 formats store the exponent with a bias, so you decode the exponent by taking the bits that encode it and subtracting the bias that was added in. (In the single-precision format, which has a bias of 127, if 130 was stored, the actual exponent is 130−127 = 3.) Except certain codes represent other things. The stored code of zero represents an exponent of −126, not −127…

… The zero code is special because it also indicates the significand is subnormal. Decoding the significand is another part. Still in the single-precision IEEE-754 format, 23 bits of the significand are stored in the significand field. A 24th bit, the leading bit, is 1 if the exponent field as a normal code and is 0 if the exponent field as the subnormal code. In any case, whatever the format is, you decode it to make a floating-point representation, which can be: A variable representing the sign (+ or −), a variable representing the exponent, and a variable representing the signficand…

… Then you prepare this number for encoding into a new format. You figure out whether the significand will fit into the new format without change (including considering how many digits of it can be kept if the exponent is very small). If it needs a change, you change it according to a round rule. There are several choices for rounding rules. To-nearest, ties-to-even is the most common…

… While adjusting the significand, you may need to adjust the exponent (and the significand), in case the rounding puts the significand outside the normal interval. Then you figure out whether the exponent fits in the new format. If not, you may need to declare an exception (overflow or underflow). Otherwise, you now have a sign, an exponent, and a significand that will fit in the new format. Then you encode those according to the rules for the new format. Those are the basics.
